# Saber se estou em uma região através de latitude e longitude

Tags: php, google-maps

Preciso saber através de coordenadas se estou na área de uma região,  no caso, o código abaixo está em PHP com polígono, mas não está dando certo. Será que estou errando a questão de coordenada (x, y)?

Procurei algo com a API do Google Maps, mas até agora nada.

```
<?php
$vertices_x = array(-4.0680,-4.0352,-4.1180,-4.0708,); // x-coordinates of the vertices of the polygon
$vertices_y = array( -63.1391,-63.0330,-63.1065, -63.0087); // y-coordinates of the vertices of the polygon
$points_polygon = count($vertices_x); // number vertices
//$longitude_x = $_GET["longitude"]; // x-coordinate of the point to test
//$latitude_y = $_GET["latitude"]; // y-coordinate of the point to test
//// For testing.  This point lies inside the test polygon.
 $longitude_x = 4.0756;
 $latitude_y =  -63.0753;

if (is_in_polygon($points_polygon, $vertices_x, $vertices_y, $longitude_x, $latitude_y)){
  echo "estou na area";
}
else echo "nao estou na area";


function is_in_polygon($points_polygon, $vertices_x, $vertices_y, $longitude_x, $latitude_y)
{
  $i = $j = $c = 0;
  for ($i = 0, $j = $points_polygon-1 ; $i < $points_polygon; $j = $i++) {
    if ( (($vertices_y[$i] > $latitude_y != ($vertices_y[$j] > $latitude_y)) &&
    ($longitude_x < ($vertices_x[$j] - $vertices_x[$i]) * ($latitude_y - $vertices_y[$i]) / ($vertices_y[$j] - $vertices_y[$i]) + $vertices_x[$i]) ) ) 
        $c = !$c;
  }
  return $c;
}
?>
```

Comment: Algo bem simila isso http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-polygon.html mais também nao funcionou

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Tentei abrir mais nao exibiu nada

Comment: entendi pra colocar la no meu codigo

Comment: Deu certo agora so esta dando um erro aqui    $c = !$c;

Comment: Onde tem `//  $i = $j = $c = 0;` coloca `$c = 0;`

Comment: Perfeito muito muito Obrigado !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750275/haversine-formula-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode simplificar a função apenas verificando se as coordenadas `$longitude_x` e `$latitude_y` estão dentro o polígono com as vértices informadas nas arrays:

```
function is_in_polygon($points_polygon, $vertices_x, $vertices_y, $longitude_x, $latitude_y)
{
   $c = 0;
  for ($i = 0, $j = $points_polygon-1 ; $i < $points_polygon; $j = $i++) {
   if(
      $latitude_y <= $vertices_y[$i] && $latitude_y >= $vertices_y[$j] &&
      $longitude_x >= $vertices_x[$j] && $longitude_x <= $vertices_x[$i]
   )
   $c = !$c;
  }
  return $c;
}
```

A função verifica se a coordenada Y é *menor ou igual* do que os 3 primeiros vértices e *maior ou igual* que o último, e o mesmo com a coordenada X. Para que o ponto dado pelas coordenadas X,Y (*lng* e *lat*, respectivamente) esteja dentro da área do polígono, as 4 condições do `if` devem ser verdadeiras.

Comment: Nao entendi no caso vou colocar somente uma coordenada isso ?

Comment: Nao. O resto do codigo nao muda, muda apenas a funçao.

Comment: Entendi ja consegui perfeito !